# Liferay 6.2 ga6 error

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

```html
BUILD FAILED
E:\Microspace-Utility\liferay GA6\ant-sdk-ga6-\portlets\build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Microspace-Utility\liferay GA6\ant-sdk-ga6\build-common-plugins.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Microspace-Utility\liferay GA6\ant-sdk-ga6\build-common.xml:60: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Microspace-Utility\liferay GA6\ant-sdk-ga6\build-common-ivy.xml:130: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Microspace-Utility\liferay GA6\ant-sdk-ga6\build-common-ivy.xml:81: HTTP Authorization failure
```

i am using liferay 6.2 ga6 with plugins sdk of liferay-sdk-ga6 when i am trying to create new portlet for the first time i am facing HTTP Authorization failure . My system is under proxy so in the build-common-ivy.xml file i have added the below line

```js
<setproxy proxyhost="172.21.2.17" proxyport="80" />
```

but i am facing the same issue.

But previously i was using liferay 6.2 ga2 with liferay-sdk-ga2 with same configuration and there everything works perfectly fine.

So i would like to know how this can be fixed and what is difference b/w this two versions and can i use liferay ga2 for by production. and how long support would be provided for ga2. and can i use liferay ga6 with plugins sdk liferay-sdk-ga2??

Comment: Plz share the error logs and the changes you tried.

Comment: Have you got a trusted certificate for the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Your post is short on details. It would be beneficial to have your entire build xml file, a copy paste of your logs, explicit information about your authentication type, and your portal ext properties file. However, off a hunch, I believe this is a known issue with liferay. Go into your build.{USERNAME}.properties file. Add there two lines

```
ivy.version = 2.3.0 
ivy.jar.url = http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.version}/ivy-${ivy.version}.jar
```

Give it another go with those properties